# Не получается получить содержимое с помощью file_get_contents()

Tags: php, json, парсер

Адрес страны с содержимым она имеет json  формат 
 не буду обрабатывать ее с помощью php мне главное получить содержимое и распечатать его на своей странице

https://tickets.fifa.com/API/WCachedL1/ru/BasicCodes/GetBasicCodesAvailavilityDemmand?currencyId=USD

```
$res = file_get_contents('https://tickets.fifa.com/API/WCachedL1/ru/BasicCodes/GetBasicCodesAvailavilityDemmand?currencyId=USD');
print $res;
```

получаю просто белый экран

если это защита неужели нет способа ее обойти?

Comment: скопировал ваш код без изменений, выполнил на своем сервере и получил полностью всю страницу.
Вы случайно не через javascript этот метод запускаете ?
попробуйте сделать так:
echo $res; die;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://tickets.fifa.com/API/WCachedL1/ru/BasicCodes/GetBasicCodesAvailavilityDemmand?currencyId=USD'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 
print $result;
```

Comment: почти то то что надо
но какие заголовки передать чтобы браузер понимал что это json файл?
так как при попытке сохранить браузер предлагает сохранить его как html

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов всмысле? ничего не надо. `var_dump(json_decode($result));`

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов я вас не так понял. Сохранить в браузер как HTML, а чего вы ожидали? какой формат вы хотели увидеть? браузеру не надо понимать что это JSON, понимают это скрипты(либо js, либо php), которые потом функцией `json_decode` преобразуют в массив и с ним работают.